# remote: Permission to XXX/.git denied to YYY. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX//': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github, windows-10, push

I think previously I used this command and entered my user and pass of the `YYY` user, but now I want to do it for another `XXX` user, but I get this error message:

```
remote: Permission to XXX/coursera-test.git denied to YYY.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX/coursera-test/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I enter a new username and password?
I use `WindowsPowerShell` on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to `Control Panel>User Accounts>Manage Windows Credentials` and removed the `github` credentials. Then i tried `git push` again and this time it asked for new login information and I could change it and do the job!